# Search in sql database gives error on homepage

Tags: php, sql, search

searching in http://vampiros.bplaced.net/index.php for (example: DUFF) gives this Error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= '[]'OR name = '[]'OR team = '[]'' at line 1
```

Dreamweaver doesnt find a syntax error. Can anybody help me?

```
<?php

//Include connection file
include "connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   PES_ONLINE_DATABASE";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE playerID = '[$search_term]'";
    $sql .= "OR name = '[$search_term]'";
    $sql .= "OR team = '[$search_term]'";
    }

$Tabelle_anzeigen = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="index.php">

Search: <input type="text" name"search_box" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Durchsuche die Datenbank">  </form>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">


<tr>
    <td><strong>playerID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>team</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Tabelle_anzeigen)) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["playerID"];?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["name"];?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row["team"];?> </td>
 </tr> 
 <?php } ?>


 </table>
```

Comment: You forgot the equals sign between `name` and `search_box`, in your form.  As a result, `$_POST['search_box']` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put spaces like below before where an or's

```
$sql .= " WHERE playerID = '[$search_term]'";

$sql .= " OR name = '[$search_term]'";

$sql .= " OR team = '[$search_term]'";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But somehow... he returns nothing when i type "DUFF", maybe do you know where the problem is?

Comment: try to print your query `echi $sql;` and check what was wrong and no need for []'s simply put `'$search_term'`

Comment: Hm thank you... it searches now but gives me always the same uotput no matter what i search for...